# Intellij can't run app on Genymotion(but can start it)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, genymotion

I tried to use genymotion instead of emulator.But after installing the genymotion and intellij plugin,I found that I can't run app on the genymotion.The target devices which I choose is"Show chooser dialog" but there is no genymotion even I can start the genymotion with the plugin.
The version of intellij is 12.1.4,and the genymotion is 1.1.0.

Comment: Do you see it in `adb devices` output?

Comment: Yes,I can see it in adb devices

Answer (score 11):

I just resolve the same problem as you have encountered.

First, close Genymotion relate application / emulator

Second, uninstall Genymotion plugin for IntelliJ

Third, install Genymotion plugin for IntelliJ

At last, start Genymotion emulator, then bring up adb console, type adb devices to see if your device is listed.

If the answer is yes, go to IntelliJ and run the application with the Target Device option set to >Show chooser dialog.

You should be able to see your Genymotion emulator in the running device list now.

Hope it helps.

(Installed IntelliJ12 on Win7)

Comment: Thank you very much.In the second step,I can see the devices using the adb console.However,I already choose Show chooser dialog but not take effect

Comment: I did not unintall and install again. Instead I just selected "show chooser dialog" in the run config and I saw it there

Comment: My problem: Even though I could see my genymotion device with 'adb devices', I kept getting 'Create your emulator dialog'.                             Solution (found in your answer): IntelliJ -> Run -> Edit Configurations -> Target Device -> selecting 'Show Chooser Dialog' helped me choose my VM. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ2Ru.png << see this image

I set it in Choose process, and choose ip of genymotion device and it will show in adb device when run

i use intellij idea 12.1.6 and genymotion 1.3.0